# Debian 12 - Unable to login using my key, and still able to login using password, but this is disabled

Tags: debian

I successfully upgraded a Debian 11 to Debian 12

A single strange thing is happening

I have a conf to override some settings

- I disabled root login
- Moved to port 1122
- Disabled auth using password
- Enabled auth using keys

  ```
  root@localhost:/etc/ssh/ssh_config.d# cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/realtebo.conf
  # Override from realtebo
  Port 1122
  PermitRootLogin no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  PubkeyAuthentication yes
  ```

At now I

- must use port 1122
- cannot login using root
- **can login using password**
- **cannot login using pubkey**

What damn is causing these 2 strange behaviours?

I already ensured that main config file is including mine.

Anyway, if I change directly the main config file [that I want to avoid], the server doesn't allow no more login using password but still refuses my pubkey, and I checked ,. is still in the `authorized_keys` and also is my rsa pub key i am using on all of my Debian 11.

What is changed to OpenSSH into Debian 12?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> - **can login using password**

In the main `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file, there is a comment:

```
# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the KbdInteractiveAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via KbdInteractiveAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin prohibit-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and KbdInteractiveAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes
```

If your configuration did not disable `KbdInteractiveAuthentication`, it allows PAM to perform the equivalent of password authentication through a slightly different code path that's originally intended for challenge/response-type authentication modules... but technically "display a password prompt" can be a challenge, and "enter a valid password" a valid response to it.

The default configuration should include an uncommented `KbdInteractiveAuthentication no`, but try

```
diff -u /usr/share/openssh/sshd_config /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

to double-check that your current main `sshd` configuration file actually matches the default one.

Also, note that the default behavior of `sshd` when password authentication is disabled is to still display a password prompt. In this situation, the prompt will be completely fake and its only purpose is to make an intruder waste their time futilely trying to guess passwords. So if you see a password prompt, it does not necessarily mean password authentication is actually available.

If you feel this is not useful, you could add `AuthenticationMethods publickey` to your `realtebo.conf` to stop `sshd` from even offering any password prompt (neither fake nor real).

---

> - **cannot login using pubkey**

The new version has a new default PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms setting. It's long, but more notable in what it *doesn't* include (quoted from `man sshd_config`):

> **PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms**
>
> [...]
>
> The default for this option is:
>
> ```
>            ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,
>            ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,
>            ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,
>            ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,
>            sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,
>            sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,
>            rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,
>            rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,
>            ssh-ed25519,
>            ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,
>            sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,
>            sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,
>            rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256
> ```

Notably the old standbys, `ssh-rsa` and `ssh-dss`, **are no longer there by default.** You can still add them in if you need to, and in your case, adding `ssh-rsa` might help... but if that's the case, you really should update your SSH client to a version that supports the `rsa-sha2-*` public key algorithms. Your existing key is fine, just the algorithm it's used in needs an upgrade.

---

So, you might try adding two settings to your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/realtebo.conf`:

```
KbdInteractiveAuthentication no
PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

If pubkey authentication still doesn't work after that, use `journalctl -u ssh.service` to view the messages logged by `sshd` to see exactly why it rejects your public key.

(Yes, the name of service that runs `sshd` is indeed `ssh.service` in Debian and derivatives, rather than `sshd.service` as in RHEL/Fedora and their derivatives. Historical reasons. Silly, but that's life.)

Note that you can view the effective `sshd` configuration by running `sshd -T`. If your configuration includes any `Match` conditionals, you can add `-C keyword=value` style options to provide the necessary information for those conditions, to check how matching the conditions affects the effective configuration in each case. See `man sshd` for more details.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation, It works (both nededed, KbdInteractiveAuthentication no and PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa). Please note that:  " So if you see a password prompt, it does not necessarily mean password authentication is actually available." . Actually it was a real prompt, entering password let user log in

Comment: Good to know - I'll soon be updating my own Debian 11 server to 12, I'll have to pay extra attention to SSH.